# Terracotta Ehcache: server disconnects during debug

Tags: java, debugging, ehcache, terracotta

I found out, that when I connect by debugger to the application, and starting to debug, 
the connection to terracotta server is lost (?) and in the terracotta server logs next messages are appeared:

> 2012-03-30 13:45:06,758 [L2_L1:TCComm Main Selector Thread_R (listen
>   0.0.0.0:9510)] WARN com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthChecker Impl. DSO Server
>   - 127.0.0.1:55112 might be in Long GC. GC count since last ping reply : 1 2012-03-30 13:45:27,761 [L2_L1:TCComm Main Selector Thread_R
>   (listen 0.0.0.0:9510)] WARN
>   com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthChecker Impl. DSO Server
>   - 127.0.0.1:55112 might be in Long GC. GC count since last ping reply : 1 2012-03-30 13:45:31,761 [L2_L1:TCComm Main Selector Thread_R
>   (listen 0.0.0.0:9510)] WARN
>   com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthChecker Impl. DSO Server
>   - 127.0.0.1:55112 might be in Long GC. GC count since last ping reply : 2

...

> 2012-03-30 13:46:37,768 [L2_L1:TCComm Main Selector Thread_R (listen
>   0.0.0.0:9510)] ERROR com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthChecke rImpl. DSO Server
>   - 127.0.0.1:55112 might be in Long GC. GC count since last ping reply : 10. But its too long. No more retries 2012-03-30 13:46:38,768
>   [HealthChecker] INFO
>   com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthCheckerImpl. DSO Server
>   - 127.0.0.1:55112 is DEAD 2012-03-30 13:46:38,768 [HealthChecker] ERROR com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ConnectionHealthCheckerImpl: DSO
>   Server - Declared connection dead 
>   ConnectionID(1.0b1994ac80f14b7191080bdc3f38582a) idle time 45317ms
>   2012-03-30 13:46:38,768 [L2_L1:TCWorkerComm # 0_R] WARN
>   com.tc.net.protocol.transport.ServerMessageTransport -
>   ConnectionID(1.0b1994ac80f14b71 91080bdc3f38582a): CLOSE EVENT :
>   com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionJDK14@5158277: connected: false, closed:
>   true local=127.0.0.1:9510 remote=127.0.0 .1:55112 connect=[Fri Mar 30
>   13:34:22 BST 2012] idle=2001ms [207584 read, 229735 write]. STATUS :
>   DISCONNECTED

...

> 2012-03-30 13:46:38,799 [L2_L1:TCWorkerComm # 0_R] INFO
>   com.tc.objectserver.persistence.sleepycat.SleepycatPersistor - Deleted
>   client state fo r ChannelID=[1] 2012-03-30 13:46:38,801
>   [WorkerThread(channel_life_cycle_stage, 0)] INFO
>   com.tc.objectserver.handler.ChannelLifeCycleHandler - : Received tran
>   sport disconnect.  Shutting down client ClientID[1] 2012-03-30
>   13:46:38,801 [WorkerThread(channel_life_cycle_stage, 0)] INFO
>   com.tc.objectserver.persistence.impl.TransactionStoreImpl - shutdownC
>   lient() : Removing txns from DB : 0

After this is happened, any operation with cache, like `getWithLoader` just doesn't answer, until terracotta server won't be restarted again.

Question: how can it be fixed/reconfigured? I assume, it can happen in production also (and actually sometimes happens) if for some (any) reason application will hang/staled/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to get you started.

TC connections betwee server and client are considered dead when the applicable HealthCheck fails. The default values for the HealthCheck assume a very stable and performant network. I recommend you familiarize yourself with the details and the calculations on

http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/3.5.2/terracotta-server-array/high-availability#85916

So typically you begin with
a) making sure your network doesn't hiccup occasionally
b) setting the TC HealthCheck values a bit higher

If the problem persists I'd recommend posting directly on the TC forums (they'll help you even if you only use the open-source edition, may take a few days to reply though.